# Is there any option to render list of 300 product and their details using pagination..?

Tags: react-redux, react-native, react-native-flatlist

> I am already use `Flatlist` its working properly.
>   if i am scroll then loadmore data from `pagination`. I am load `20` product data from pagination `API`.
>   but its to late and slow for to render `300` product list. Is any Solution for my problem please tell me.
>   Advanced Thanks to all.

Comment: Seems like more of a server side issue. First make sure API is fast enough to provide data on the go. No matter how good you handle it in frontend, it wont feel fluid if the backend API is slow itself.

Comment: Server Side data is to much faster i was already check server side response time ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the ones below :

> Props One way to improve your FlatList is by tweaking it's props. Here
>   are a list of props that can help your with that.
>
> **removeClippedSubviews** You can set the removeClippedSubviews prop to
>   true, which unmount components that are off of the window.
>
> Win: This is very memory friendly, as you will always have a little
>   rendered list.
>
> Trade offs: Be aware, that this implementation can have bugs, such as
>   missing content if you use it on a component that will not unmount
>   (such as a navigation route). It also can be less performant, having
>   choppy scroll animations for big lists with complex items on
>   not-so-good devices, as it make crazy amounts of calculations per
>   scroll.
>
> **maxToRenderPerBatch** You can set the maxToRenderPerBatch={number},
>   which is a VirtualizedList prop that can be passed directly to
>   FlatList. With this, you can control the amount of items rendered per
>   batch, which is the next chunk of items rendered on every scroll.
>
> Win: Setting a bigger number means less visual blank areas when
>   scrolling (a better the fill rate).
>
> Trade offs: More items per batch means less JavaScript performance,
>   which means less responsiveness (clicking a item and opening the
>   detail). If you have a static and non-interactive list, this could be
>   the way to go.
>
> **initialNumToRender** You can set the initialNumToRender={number}. This
>   means the initial amount of items to render.
>
> Win: You can set this value to the precise number of items that would
>   cover the screen for every device. This can be a big performance boost
>   when rendering the list component.
>
> Trade offs: You are most likely to see blank areas when setting a low
>   initialNumToRender.
>
> **windowSize** You can set the windowSize={number}. The number passed here
>   is a measurement unit where 1 is equivalent to your viewport height.
>   The default value is 21, being 10 viewports above, 10 below, and one
>   in between.
>
> Win: If you're worried mainly about performance, you can set a bigger
>   windowSize so your list will run smoothly and with less blank space.
>   If you're mainly worried about memory consumption, you can set a lower
>   windowSize so your rendered list will be smaller.
>
> Trade offs: For a bigger windowSize, you will have a bigger memory
>   consumption. For a lower windowSize, you will have lower performance
>   and bigger change of seeing blank areas.
>
> **legacyImplementation** This prop, when true, make your FlatList rely on
>   the older ListView, instead of VirtualizedList.
>
> Win: This will make your list definitely perform better, as it removes
>   virtualization and render all your items at once.
>
> Trade offs: Your memory consumption goes to the roof and chances are
>   good that a big list (100+) with complex items will crash your app. It
>   also fires a warning that the above tweaks will not work, because
>   you're now on a ListView.
>
> **disableVirtualization** You will see people advocation the use of this
>   prop on some issues. But this is deprecated now. This used to do
>   something similar to legacyImplementation.

try the once above to display 300 data efficiently , if it doesnt work will tell you about pagination .

Hope it helps .feel freee for doubts

Comment: Thanks Brother i am trying this one solution first